# Interactive matplotlib plot in PySimpleGUI

Tags: matplotlib, pysimplegui, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to get the RectangleSelector form matplotlib.widgets to work with PySimpleGUI.
I'm basing my test code on the RectangleSelector demo shown in the accepted answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052379/matplotlib-draw-a-selection-area-in-the-shape-of-a-rectangle-with-the-mouse).

I'm getting the plot to show in PySimpleGUI but it's not interactive. Is it even possible in PySimpleGUI to have interactive matplotlib widgets?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.widgets  import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

xdata = np.linspace(0,9*np.pi, num=301)
ydata = np.sin(xdata)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata)


def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata

    rect = plt.Rectangle( (min(x1,x2),min(y1,y2)), np.abs(x1-x2), np.abs(y1-y2) )
    ax.add_patch(rect)


rs = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                       drawtype='box', useblit=False, button=[1],
                       minspanx=5, minspany=5, spancoords='pixels',
                       interactive=True)
                       

layout = [[sg.Canvas(key="-CANVAS-")]]

window = sg.Window('test', layout, finalize=True, element_justification='center', font='Helvetica 16')
draw_figure(window["-CANVAS-"].TKCanvas, fig)
event, values = window.read()
```

**Edit:** Thanks to MikeyB for the pointer, I now have the following code, which shows an interactive plot, but it's still not possible to draw rectangles. The callback function doesn't seem to be firing. New code below:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets  import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib.figure as figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

# instantiate matplotlib figure
fig = figure.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
DPI = fig.get_dpi()
fig.set_size_inches(505 * 2 / float(DPI), 707 / float(DPI))

# ------------------------------- This is to include a matplotlib figure in a Tkinter canvas
def draw_figure_w_toolbar(canvas, fig, canvas_toolbar):
    if canvas.children:
        for child in canvas.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    if canvas_toolbar.children:
        for child in canvas_toolbar.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    toolbar = Toolbar(figure_canvas_agg, canvas_toolbar)
    toolbar.update()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=1)


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata

    rect = plt.Rectangle( (min(x1,x2),min(y1,y2)), np.abs(x1-x2), np.abs(y1-y2) )
    print(rect)
    ax.add_patch(rect)


class Toolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Toolbar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# ------------------------------- PySimpleGUI CODE

layout = [
    [sg.B('start', key='start')],
    [sg.Canvas(key='controls_cv')],
    [sg.Column(
        layout=[
            [sg.Canvas(key='fig_cv',
                       # it's important that you set this size
                       size=(500 * 2, 700)
                       )]
        ],
        background_color='#DAE0E6',
        pad=(0, 0)
    )],
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'start':
        x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
        y = np.sin(x)
        line, = ax.plot(x, y)
        rs = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                       drawtype='box', useblit=False, button=[1],
                       minspanx=5, minspany=5, spancoords='pixels',
                       interactive=True)
        draw_figure_w_toolbar(window['fig_cv'].TKCanvas, fig, window['controls_cv'].TKCanvas)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add

```py
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

to your callback-function if you want the plot to be updated after the callback has triggered!

here's an updated version of your code that works just fine:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets  import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib.figure as figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# instantiate matplotlib figure
fig = figure.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
DPI = fig.get_dpi()
fig.set_size_inches(505 * 2 / float(DPI), 707 / float(DPI))

# ------------------------------- This is to include a matplotlib figure in a Tkinter canvas
def draw_figure_w_toolbar(canvas, fig, canvas_toolbar):
    if canvas.children:
        for child in canvas.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    if canvas_toolbar.children:
        for child in canvas_toolbar.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    toolbar = Toolbar(figure_canvas_agg, canvas_toolbar)
    toolbar.update()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=1)


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata

    rect = plt.Rectangle( (min(x1,x2),min(y1,y2)), np.abs(x1-x2), np.abs(y1-y2) )
    print(rect)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    fig.canvas.draw()

class Toolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Toolbar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# ------------------------------- PySimpleGUI CODE

layout = [
    [sg.B('start', key='start')],
    [sg.Canvas(key='controls_cv')],
    [sg.Column(
        layout=[
            [sg.Canvas(key='fig_cv',
                       # it's important that you set this size
                       size=(500 * 2, 700)
                       )]
        ],
        background_color='#DAE0E6',
        pad=(0, 0)
    )],
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'start':
        x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
        y = np.sin(x)
        line, = ax.plot(x, y)
        rs = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                       drawtype='box', useblit=False, button=[1],
                       minspanx=5, minspany=5, spancoords='pixels',
                       interactive=True)
        draw_figure_w_toolbar(window['fig_cv'].TKCanvas, fig, window['controls_cv'].TKCanvas)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it even possible in PySimpleGUI to have interactive matplotlib widgets?

Yes.

The demo program on the project's GitHub shows how to make an interactive Matplotlib drawing.

https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Matplotlib_Embedded_Toolbar.py

You need to embed the controls into the window.

Comment: Thanks! I used this demo as a starting point now and updated the code in my question, but still no luck on getting anything to draw.